# How to get value in accordance with the sequence ID name of the onchange event?

Tags: php, javascript, onchange, xmlhttprequest

There is one table that have fields included the add row button. I am using **onchange event to call data from other tables**, so when I select an option in the option box can automatically get the value that has been selected earlier `(do not need input the value manually).`
Then I add row in the same table and after that I select one option back in the box option and get different values ​​from the first, `the problem is the values ​​obtained appear in the first box, not in the second box.`

For the html example:

```
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <td>No</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Class</td>
        <td>Point</td>
        <td>Action</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td>1</td>
        <td><select name="name">
            <option value="#">&nbsp;</option>
            <?php
                    opendb();
                $query = "SELECT * FROM student";
                $result = mysql_query($query);
                while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                    $ID = $data['ID'];
                    $Name = $data['Name'];
                    echo "<option value='$ID'>$Name</option>";
                }
            ?>
             </select>
        </td>
        <td><select name='class' onchange="choosepoint(this);">
            <option value="#">&nbsp;</option>
            <?php
                    opendb();
                $query = "SELECT * FROM student2";
                $result = mysql_query($query);
                while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                        $ID1 = $data['ID'];
                    $class = $data['Class'];
                    echo "<option value='$ID'>$class</option>";
                }
            ?>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
                <div id="point" name="point"></div>
            </td>
            <td><input type="button" value=" + " onClick="addRowToTable();"> | <input type="button" value=" - " onClick="removeRowFromTable();"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What I was searching, the problem I found here:

```
function choosepoint(combobox)
{
    var kode = combobox.value;
    if (!kode) return;
    xmlhttp.open('get', '../template/get_point.php?kode='+kode, true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if ((xmlhttp.readyState == 4) && (xmlhttp.status == 200))
        {
             document.getElementById("point").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
        return false;
    }
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

If the ID name "point" changed to "point2" then the value will appear in the second box, but the value in the first box missing.

So I tried looping to get the value of the ID name to be point, point2, point3 etc. (depending on how many want to add the rows).

```
function choosepoint(combobox)
{
    var kode = combobox.value;
    if (!kode) return;
    xmlhttp.open('get', '../template/get_point.php?kode='+kode, true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if ((xmlhttp.readyState == 4) && (xmlhttp.status == 200))
        {
             Var tbl = document.getElementById("table");
             var r = tbl.length;
             var i = r;
             document.getElementById("point"+ i).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
        return false;
    }
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

The results I've got is null or no values, cannot run or not get the value to be point, point2, point3 etc.
Is there any wrong script that I've made? Need a big help m(_ _)m.

Thanks.

**Update: This's for the solved.**

```
function choosepoint(combobox)
{
    var kode = combobox.value;
    if (!kode) return;
    xmlhttp.open('get', '../template/get_point.php?kode='+kode, true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if ((xmlhttp.readyState == 4) && (xmlhttp.status == 200))
        {
            var tbl = document.getElementById("table");
        var r = tbl.rows.length;
            var add = document.getElementById("point"+r);

        add.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
        return false;
    }
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

Comment: Can you reduce your question to a much simpler form?  I can't follow what you're actually asking.  Please provide simple steps to describe what you do on your web page, what code gets called and what result you're expecting but not getting.

Comment: @jfriend00 Ok, here is for the example:(as you see on the table form).
No 1 I will select AAA for the name, and select II for the class, when I selected II on the class I will get a point automatically in the <a id="point" name="point" href="">100.00(here the point will appear)</a> without I input the value manually (of course by using onchange if it wants to be happen).

Comment: @jfriend00 Then when I want to add row there will be number 2 right? So No 2 I will select BBB for the name, select III for the class, then when I selected III on the class, the point I get will appear in <a id="point" name="point" href="">80.00(here)</a>.There are two data with different points, 100.00 and 80.00 for no 1 and 2. Nuh, my question and the problem is The results point contained on No. 2, is 80.00 it does not appear exactly at No. 2 but it does appear at no 1. Coz we know the point we got at no 1 is 100.00.
So how to fix that each data or numbers have their points self?

Comment: @jfriend00 I hope you get what I meant!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you given the id for the table as **"table"** and then you have accessed **"document.getElementById('table')"** and then you have used **"tbl.length"** which resulted in null or no value. The problem here is that when you use **getElementById** you don't have the property **"length"**. In order to access the number of tables use the following

```
<table name="table">
and then
tbl = document.getElementById('table')
r = tbl.rows.length; //This will give you the row length.
function choosepoint(combobox)
{
    var kode = combobox.value;
    if (!kode) return;
    xmlhttp.open('get', '../template/get_point.php?kode='+kode, true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if ((xmlhttp.readyState == 4) && (xmlhttp.status == 200))
        {
             Var tbl = document.getElementById('table')
             var r = tbl.rows.length;
              alert(document.getElementById("point"+r));//This should be object. If undefined then you don't have any element.
              **//Edit Part**
              if(document.getElementById("point"+r))
                 document.getElementById("point"+r).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
              else
              {
                  var cellRight = row.insertCell(3);//The cell or column number can be any here am using it as third column.
                  var div = document.createElement('div');
                  div.id = 'point' + r;
                  cellRight.appendChild(div);
                  cellRight.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
              }
             **//Till Here**
        }
        return false;
    }
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @AmGates for the help.
I tried your codes and it gave me the value, was 1. When I intended to add row, the value I got was 1 not 2. I want to get it from 1, 2, 3, 4 and so on.

Comment: Instead I changed to:
`<table id="table">
tbl = document.getElementById('table');
i = tbl.rows.length;
It gives me length sequentially (1,2,3,4 so on).
BUT I still have a problem, when I add the variable i (which has the length) to here `document.getElementById("point"+ i).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;` the "point" doesn't show be "point1" or "point2" or "point3" (depending on how many rows I added). Have any idea?

Comment: The alert results is null. I was wondering, why if I only alert the var r = tbl.rows.length it got the values, but didn't get at the document.getElementById("point"+r)? (=,=)"a

Comment: Do you have that element in your html document with the correct ID?

Comment: Yes, I have. This is the element > `<div id="point" name="point"></div>` with the same ID too.

Comment: do you have element with id="point1" or "point2" or "point3"?

Comment: Then how can you expect the alert to show object. Show first create the div with that id and then append it to the page and then access it you will get the result

Comment: Create the div with "point1", "point2", and "point3" IDs? If so, I have made them and yes I got the result. But how if there is more than three point ID? Let say, if I had fifty (point50), should I create the div ID from point1 to point50 manually? It would take a long time, wouldn't it?

Comment: No it is not that you have to create it manually. You can create at the run time using the document.createElement method.

Comment: You can check my edited answer for dynamic creation of the div.

Comment: wa wa wa, this is what I wanted, thankyou AmGates. Oh yeah, about creation of div element, before you asked me to create the div, I have created it in the Javascript for adding row > you can check in here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/kanon/KrZBQ/). What should I do? Just change this `document.body.appendChild(sDiv)` to the element that I have created in the Javascript (add row)?

Comment: The firebug said "**row.insertCell() isn't a function**" > `var cellRight = row.insertCell(3)` <.
If I add a variable, which is `var row = tbl.insertRow(r);
var cellRight = row.insertCell(3);` the firebug said "**Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount**".
Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: Hey edit your original question and update it with the latest code you are using

Comment: Uh, sorry for the trouble. It is working now.
Thanks @AmGates for the big big help m(_ _)m.